# Mathematical Idea with the purpose to store data more efficiently

Tags: database, dataframe, logic, storage, computer-science

dear reader

I have been thinking about how to store data efficiently since the beginning of my studies and while taking a shower, I came up with the following idea:

For example, you take a picture and convert that picture into 0(zeros) and 1(ones). Then you take this eternally long number and divide it by e.g. 10 then again by 10 and then again by 10 etc. and at the end you have a small number. Now the small number and the calculation path are stored and if someone wants to read the data, they only have to perform the inverse operation to get the result.
The idea is too good to be true --> my gut feeling tells me. But I would still like to know why this should not work?

Kind regards

Hello, dear reader

I have been thinking about how to store data efficiently since the beginning of my studies and while taking a shower, I came up with the following idea:

For example, you take a picture and convert that picture into 0(zeros) and 1(ones). Then you take this eternally long number and divide it by e.g. 10 then again by 10 and then again by 10 etc. and at the end you have a small number. Now the small number and the calculation path are stored and if someone wants to read the data, they only have to perform the inverse operation to get the result.
The idea is too good to be true --> my gut feeling tells me. But I would still like to know why this should not work?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Fun theorem.  No bijection on the natural numbers can map every number to a smaller one.  Proof by contradiction, consider F(F(1)).

Lots of ways to map numbers 1-1 to smaller numbers such that *many* map to smaller numbers.  These are lossless compression algorithms.  Most have the property that repeated application of the algorithm make the data larger, or leave it unchanged.

In your proposal, to the extent I understand it, you would have to store all the remainders of the division, which would be as large as the original data.